# A book on the Lasker - Capablanca World Championship Match (1921)

Tags: world-championship, capablanca, lasker

Recently I've been studying **Lasker - Capablanca World Championship Match (1921)**. Is there a book that gives the story behind the match? Also, I would appreciate the game annotations.

Best wishes and thank you.

Comment: Although not a book, all of the games should be on chessgames.com and have many comments.

Comment: Besides chessgames.com, all I could find is [agadmator's Chess Channel playlist.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDnx7w_xuguEcHvN5JaeSguICUQubgjdh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capablanca's comments about the match can be found in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486231895) book.

Answer (score 2):

Kasparov's My Great Predecessors series covers all the world champions before him, including the world championship matches they participated in. The one you're interested in is dealt with in volume 1 of the series.